# JsonProperty Naming Conventions

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there any documentation which details what the `JsonProperty` naming conventions are? As in if I declare `@JsonProperty("id")` what can and cannot go inside the parenthesis?

Comment: Please remember to tag language-specific questions with the language name.

Comment: @Barmar json is language independent, and in any case it came from JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: (Or are you guessing from the `@JsonProperty("id")` syntax that this is Java? That doesn't look like Java to me...)

Comment: `@JsonProperty("id")` is not only Java, it's from Java and [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonProperty.html).

Answer (score 2):

Anything. The JSON generator itself will escape weird or wrong characters (like the new line character, that should not be present in a JSON string). But you should obviously avoid using weird characters since it will make it harder for someone parsing your JSON to understand what it means.

People just use either camel case or snake case property names in there.